# Password not reset for Single Sign-On User

Tags: salesforce1-app, single-sign-on, change-password

Some of our Community Users who do have SF1 enabled cannot login to the S1 app, they're getting password errors. However, these users are SSO so they can't reset their passwords. What should we do to get him on SF1?

Comment: SSO passwords are maintained by identity provider. It could be many reasons why they could get a password error - can you provide some more details?

Comment: Not sure what's our identity provider, where can I check that? The exact issue was one of the affected users can login on his laptop using SSO but not in SF1 app.

Answer (score 1):

We have a custom domain enabled along with single sign on, I find a lot of our users get confused when logging into Salesforce1 and try to put their SSO credentials into the generic Salesforce login screen and forget that they need to press "Use Custom Domain" to get to our SSO authentication screen to enter their network credientials

Answer (score 0):

From [**Knowledge Article** Salesforce1 - Switch Login servers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187717&language=en_US&type=1):

> **If you want Salesforce1 redirect to a single sign-on location, or
>   login using a Community URL you can configure the app to point to a
>   different page during login:**
>
> To Change the login host on ***Apple iOS***:
>
> - On the Log In page, tap [image: Settings].
> - You can also select one of the predefined instances: **Production** or **Sandbox**.
> - For a My Domain or Community URL
> - Tap + to add a new login host.
> - Enter the host name URL of the new instance. Don’t include http:// in the host name.
> - Optionally, enter a label for the new instance.
> - Tap **Done**.
> - Tap the name of the newly created instance, then log in.
>
> To Change the login host on ***Android***:
>
> - On the Log In page, tap 3 dot menu at top right [image] (note: depending on your Android setup, you may not see this icon. You will
>     need to use the phone's built-in menu button)
> - Tap "Change Server"
> - You can also select one of the predefined instances: **Production** or **Sandbox**.
> - Tap "Add Connection" button
> - Enter a name for the new instance.
> - Enter host name URL of the new instance. **Include** the https:// in the host name.
> - Tap **Apply**
> - Tap the name of the newly created instance, then **Apply**, then log in.

Comment: We tried this one but, same error. Is it safe if we will uncheck the "Is Single Sign-On Enabled" on the affected user's profile so we can reset his password? Once complete, we will check that option again. Any thoughts?

Comment: SSO is not using Salesforce passwords to authenticate users. You can uncheck SSO, and they can even use Salesforce login to access the system  if your current configuration is allowing to do so. Just make sure, when your users are asked for user name and password, they are entering the correct one (in most cases this would be domain user names and password, case sensitive)